# Extract first word after pattern that includes `[...]`

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have an issue when I try to extract the first word after `grep` matches my pattern .

Let me show you an example :

```
cat test.txt
[profile dev]
xxx
xxx
[profile prod]
xxx
xxx
```

now I want to extract the word after 'profile' and eventually assign it into a variable

I tried with `grep` and `awk` but it seems I can't extract only the word

`grep -oP '(?<=profile\s/)\w+' /test.txt` returns nothing 
also with `awk`:

```
awk '/^profile / {print $1}' /text.txt
```

maybe its because of the brackets or I don't know , can you help me with a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Awk pattern is failing because the word "profile" does not start the record, `[profile` does...

```
awk '/^\[profile/ {gsub(/]/,""); print $2}' test.txt
dev
prod
```

Another approach would be to load an array, using `split`:

```
awk -F'[][]' '/profile/ {p=split($2,profiles," "); print profiles[2]}' test.txt
dev
prod
```

Comment: Silly me :) , thank you for your fast response !